# Where are AWS Glue Job Delay Notification's raised to?

Tags: aws-glue

We're setting the Glue Job Delay Notification but we're not seeing where the notification is raised. We're not seeing it come through in AWS CloudWatch Events for Glue or AWS Cloudwatch Metrics. Where should the notification for AWS Glue Job delayed be raised?

Comment: Can you confirm if execution time crossed the mentioned job delay time ? execution time is different from run time of job and you should receive this delay notification in your email

Comment: I set the delay time to 1 minute to test. Will check the account's email.

Comment: We checked the inbox to the ops contact and account holder and did not have any AWS Glue job delay notification emails in them. What email address will the delay notification send to?